# R {wordcloud} package, what do the values in scale represent?

Tags: r, word-cloud

This seems like a simple question, but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere. In the R {wordcloud} package, the `wordcloud` function, there is a scale value that you can enter. The full documentation (here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wordcloud/wordcloud.pdf) says: "A vector of length 2 indicating the range of the size of the words."

I can't seem to make any sense of the values though, and I can't find any other documentation. For instance, examples have `scale=c(4,.5)` or `scale=c(8,.3)`. What do these numbers mean?

I've messed around with different values a bit, but I can't seem to figure out the pattern.
Thanks in advance for any help,
Seth

Answer (score 6):

`wordcloud` internally calculates

```
size <- (scale[1] - scale[2]) * normedFreq + scale[2]
```

where the 2 elements of `size` are used to set `strheight` and `strwidth`. These are `graphics` values described as follows:

> These functions compute the width or height, respectively, of the
>   given strings or mathematical expressions s[i] on the current plotting
>   device in user coordinates, inches or as fraction of the figure width
>   par("fin").

So, long story short, it's height and width.